# Angular app does not work without trailing slash with nginx conf

Tags: angular, nginx

I build my angular app with:

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing=all --base-href /myapp/ --deploy-url /myapp/
```

My nginx conf:

```
 server {
  listen 8090;
  server_name xyz.com;
  location /myapp {
    alias /opt/myapp/;
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

My application works with trailing slash as:
`xyz.com/myapp/`

but not without it:
`xyz.com/myapp`

Please help

Comment: Replace `alias /opt/myapp/;` with `root /opt;`

Comment: I tried but not works

Comment: What doesn't work? 404 error? Styles and JS missing? If it's the latter, do the values of `href` and `src` in `index.html` begin with `./`?

Comment: I got 301.  js files are missing